# Triple Integrals Help

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $E$ is the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ whose density at each point is proportional to the distance from the origin. Find an expression for the mass of $E$ as a Triple Integral and explain why it's difficult to compute

I believe it is difficult to compute because the region is a sphere and not a box but I'm not exactly sure how to write the triple integral

Comment: $x^2+y^2=1$ is a circle (or a cylindrical surface in 3D), not a sphere! maybe you say $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1$. In this case the problem is not so difficult and, thanks to the spherical symmetry, it is not really ''multivariable''

Comment: Use spherical coordinates.

Comment: is E supposed to be the sphere $x^2+y^2 + z^2 = 1$ or is it the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in which case what is the range of $z$?

Comment: My bad its supposed to be x^2+y^2+z^2=1

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary density $\rho$, the mass is expressible as a triple integral in spherical polar coordinates, viz. $\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^\pi d\theta\sin\theta\int_0^1 \rho(r,\,\theta,\,\phi)r^2 dr$. If $\rho$ only depends on $r$ we can first integrate out the angles, giving $4\pi\int_0^1\rho(r)r^2 dr$. The choice $\rho=kr$ from your question gives $4\pi k\int_0^1 r^3 dr=\pi k$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused here. Is this after converting to spherical coordinates. How would you express the triple integral of mass before converting to spherical coordinates?

Comment: @Emily What do you mean by "before"? No one coordinate system is "before", making others "after"; they're all equally valid, but for specific problems one may be more useful than another.

Comment: I guess I meant to say is the integral you wrote in spherical coordinates? The question I have first wants me to express the integral without using spherical coordinates and explain why it's hard to compute

Comment: Well, if you express it *without* SCs, what do you express it *with*? Do they mean Cartesian ones, viz. $\int_{-1}^1 dx\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dy\int_{\-sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} dz \rho$? I think you can see why that's hard: the limits of one variable depend on the value of another.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $\delta=kr$ is the density at distance $r$ from the center, than the mass of a spherical shell from $r$ and $r+dr$ is $m=\delta 4 \pi r^2 dr$.

Can you do from this?